# Elul Cheshbon HaNefesh

Tags: elul, repentance-teshuvah, mussar-ethics

How does one make a Cheshbon HaNefesh during Elul. I'm aware of the technique given in [Sefer Cheshbon HaNefesh](http://www.feldheim.com/cgi-bin/category.cgi?item=0-87306-774-6), but that is intended (and set up as) as a year round exercise. Is there anything more comprehensive and special that we can do for Elul?

Comment: [Gain access to a response here.](http://web.archive.org/web/20110216222223/http://www.lakewood246.com/news/20287/rabbi-yechiel-spero-time-to-get-serious-cheshbon-hanefesh.html)

Comment: https://www.chabad.org/therebbe/article_cdo/aid/5873/jewish/Hayom-Yom-Menachem-Av-27.htm